# How to set the length of input layer in lstm

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm building a LSTM model to classify some review data using Keras. Output is just 1 or 0.

I added an word embedding layer before feeding the text data into lstm layer.  Part of my code is shown below. Here is max_feature is vocabulary size. Word vector size is 2. Size of each document is maxlen. All document is already padded to the same length.

However, I'm always confused with the length of LSTM layer. Should that be the same length as the length of my documents (maxlen)? Feed in all words in each document, and get an output?.....

There are quite a few online sources explaining LSTM. But in terms of implementation, I feel not many of them give clear explainations...

Really appreciate it if someone could clarify on this.

```
# max_features: vocabulary size
# word vector size: 2
# maxlen: my document size, already padded to the same length
# Build our model
print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=max_features, output_dim= 2, input_length=maxlen ))
model.add(LSTM(units= ???? ))  
model.add(Dense(1))

model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',            
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of units in the LSTM is irrelevant to the data dimensions, units is the number of neurons/nodes in the LSTM layer.
LSTM is a recursive network, which parameters are used again and again at the same layer:
[image: image taken from http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/]

'A' represents the LSTM cell, and the amount of 'A's are the same as your input length. Units represents the hidden dimensions of 'A'.

Comment: thanks a lot for clarification!  So the amount of A is 'automatically adjusted' to the same length as my document length.  One more question is how is my word vector size (2 in this case)  fit in the lstm structure? is it the dimension of x0, x1, x2....?

Comment: The amount of 'A's in your case is maxlen (input_length = maxlen). I'm not quite sure I understand your question by word vector size = 2, your words I'm guessing are represented by a 1-hot - input_dim=vocabulary size (which is probably bigger than 2).

Comment: I have a word embedding layer. If I understand it correctly, it learns word vectors from the vocabulary (word-to-vec).  For each word, it's represented as a vector form. Here I just use 2d word vector, but it can be any dimension.   What I do not fully understand is how these word vectors get fed into the lstm network.

Comment: The embedding layer transforms each word into a vector (w2v), then the vector is fed into the LSTM by a matrix multiplication.
E.g. S = a1 a2 
The embedding layer will transform a1 to it's vector representation, then will fed it to the first LSTM cell. The dimensions of the matrix multiplication are: embedded word: |1| x |output dim (2 in your case)|
LSTM hidden dim (units): |units|. To summer up, the transformation is from |1| x |output dim| to |1| x |units|, so the embedded vector of |1| x |output dim| is multiplied by a weight matrix of |output dim| x |units|. Hope this helps.

Comment: so according to the scheme you put there, each x0, x1,.. is word vector (2d in my case), right?  Each is multiplied by a weight matrix of 2xunits, which is happening in each A block.   Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In more details: each input is a 1-hot vector of the size of vocabulary dim, the embedding layer will transform it to a 2d dim.